# Using SVG images in TinyMCE 5.4.2 editor for HCL Connections

Tags: svg, tinymce, ibm-connections, hcl-connections

We updated Tiny Editors for HCL Connections to the latest stable version 4.4.3.0. In the changelog.html I saw the following:

"Includes TinyMCE version 5.4.2-90.

Includes Textbox.io version 2.4.2.102.

> New Features:
> Allow SVG elements

I tried to upload an svg image. Using drag&drop nothing happens. When using "Insert Image", i get an error: "server.svg is invalid because the file extension svg is not in the list of allowed file extensions".

I verified that the update was successfully, Help > Version shows me:

```
TinyMCE 5.4.2
Integration for HCL Connections, version 4.4.3.0
```

So where do we need to allow svg files for the editor? We have `<restrictions enabled="false"` in the files/wikis xml config file and I couldn't find any documentation about this new feature.

Answer (score 0):

While TinyMCE supports SVGs, HCL Connections doesn't: It got blocked after pasting in the editor and uploading plain SVG files also doesn't work. So I asked the support and they told me:

> On further testing on allowing svg file with latest TinyMCE 5.4.2, I consulted with my extended team and I would like to inform you that the TinyMCE does included the change in the latest release to support svg file type however connections is still looking into supporting this in the future but it's currently not supported due to the inherent security risks associated with the SVG file type.